# Why my symbol is not exported with EXPORT_SYMBOL?

Tags: linux, kernel, driver

I'm making a simple kernel object. but somehow a variable is not exported with EXPORT_SYMBIL macro.
the source is:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/init.h>

MODULE_LICENSE("Dual BSD/GPL");

int hello_int __attribute__ ((__unused__));
EXPORT_SYMBOL(hello_int);

static int hello_init(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "driver loaded\n");
        return 0;
}

static void hello_exit(void)
{
        printk(KERN_ALERT "driver unloaded\n");
}

module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
```

but.

```
# insmod hello.ko
# cat /proc/kallsyms | grep hello

d9fb0000 t hello_exit   [hello]
d9fb000c t hello_init   [hello]
d9fb0000 t cleanup_module       [hello]
d9fb000c t init_module  [hello]
d9f6374e t br_hello_timer_expired       [bridge]
d9f64027 t show_hello_timer     [bridge]
d9f640fb t store_hello_time     [bridge]
d9f64264 t set_hello_time       [bridge]
d9f641ee t show_hello_time      [bridge]
```

no hello_int is there. but certainly,

```
# cat Module.symvers

0x8ed8de1a      hello_int       /home/ken/myprojects/hello/hello        EXPORT_SYMBOL
```

why? something wrong?

```
# uname -a
Linux debian-6-0-6-i386 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sun Sep 23 09:49:36 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux
```

and here is Makefile for this:

```
obj-m := hello.o

all:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

Comment: nm of the .ko lists `hello_int`?

Comment: Good question.
`$ nm hello.ko` 
`00000000 B hello_int`
It looks uninitialized data (BSS section) but 'B' means it is exported I think

Comment: I'm using debian squeeze (6.0), kernel `2.6.32-40-generic-pae`, and it displays the hello_int symbol in /proc/kallsyms. 32&64 bit seem to work correctly. I am perplexed as it should be working

Comment: Thanks, Petesh. umhhh... me either.. Did you check it with the samke Makfile which I showed?

Comment: I copy-pasted what you had written in the question. The only other suggestion I have is to initialize the variable, which may cause it to appear in your case

Comment: suggestion, thanks. I initialized the variable and actually used it in hello_init(). but result was same... no symbol in /proc/kallsyms. even though output from nm was different: `00000000 D hello_int`. well... should I give up?

Comment: I had an epiphany - CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL is not set on your kernel configuration. Looks like a later debian kernel revision enabled the flag which is why I was unable to reproduce your issue

Comment: oh dear.. I'll check it as I am home

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that the kernel is configured without [`CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL`](http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/KALLSYMS_ALL.html) set, causing it to only export functions and not variables. I'm finding it difficult to [track what happened in relation to this](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=660288), but it looks like at some point the flag was enabled in one of the kernel updates.

Comment: still I'm rebuilding kernel with CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL (I couldn't find pre-build pakage). In parallel, I made another try with two kernel modules. One is hello.ko and the other is hi.ko which access hello_int and prinked it. It was OK. regardless CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL setting, the symbol was certainly exported

Comment: the CONFIG_KALLSYMS_ALL is generally helpful in kernel debugging but is not needed to make use of exported non-function symbols from other modules. As you have noted, it worked without issue even though you could not see the symbol.